# Probability density of fermions in QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, field-theory, probability, dirac-equation

I was following the book 'Quantum Field theory and the Standard model' written by Mattehw D. Schwartz and I found something unconvincing in p.174 of the book.

In that page, it argues that the zeroth component of the Noether current (to the Dirac Lagrangian) $J_{\mu}=\bar{\psi}\gamma_{\mu}\psi$ corresponding to the global symmetry of the spinors $\psi\rightarrow e^{-i\alpha}\psi$ should be interpreted as the probability density of the fermions. That is, it argues that $J_{0}=\psi^{\dagger}\psi=\psi_{L}^{\dagger}\psi_{L}+ \psi_{R}^{\dagger}\psi_{R}$ is the probability density of the Fermions.

My issue here is, although this $J_{0}$ is a quantity that is conserved according to the continuity equation for the Noether current, it evidently is 'NOT' Lorentz invariant. This in turn means that the probability density should be different depending on what reference frame we choose to be in. How can such a quantity which is not Lorentz invariant be physically interpreted as probability density? My guess is that the 'GLOBAL' amount of charge (or probability) can somehow be Lorentz invariant when we use our usual reasoning that the boundary values should vanish at infinity, but isn't it the 'LOCAL' probability that has to be Lorentz invariant in order to constitute a physically meaningful theory? Probability of an event of observing a particle at a particular spacetime grid has to be reference frame independent at least from my understanding.

Comment: I am not a theorist and I can't comment on the actual question, but a single component of a four-vector is usually (probably never) invariant. Because of length contraction a volume element does not stay the same, so one would expect a change in scalar densities, would one not? Am I missing something?

Comment: This is more accurately the charge density, because it becomes the charge operator in quantum field theory. Schwartz is referring to an approximation of QFT, where the Dirac equation can be regarded as a probability wave equation, because of its unitary Hamiltonian. But the Lorentz invariance of probabilities is a problem. Hopefully, someone here can clear it up.

Comment: No density can be be Lorentz invariant, because the volume contracts under boosts. Densities therefore pick up a factor of $\gamma$ under a boost.

Comment: @mikestone Yes, but OP is asking how can it still be interpreted as a probability despite not being invariant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Probability of an event of observing a particle at a particular spacetime grid has to be reference frame independent

One of your problems is assuming that the particle is observed in a particular spacetime-grid.

The density is not probability divided by spacetime volume. Instead, it's "probability divided by small 3D space volume" at a particular point of time.

So, if you do a boost, the probability density changes, but the 3D space, to which the probability is associated, also changes. The original small 3D space-like hypersurface is no longer a space-like hypersurface after a Lorentz boost.

Anyway, I'm not sure if this resolves the question of probabilistic interpretation of the Dirac equation. Maybe some other answer can clear it up.

**In the full quantum field theory**, there does not exist a position basis to allow you to talk about the probability of observing a particle at a point in space.

Comment: Your explanation on not-invariant probability density does seem to make sense if we are to interpret this quantity as probability density corresponding to a local 3D spatial point not a 4D point, although whether this change of quantity under boost would be exactly as can be predicted from volume contraction under boost is still questionable.

Answer (score 0):

More generally, if $J=J^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}$ is a 4-vector current density  that satisfies a [continuity equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuity_equation) $$\partial_{\mu}J^{\mu}~=~0,\tag{1}$$
then the corresponding charge defined in one inertial frame as $$\begin{align}Q(t_1)~:=~&\int_{\{t=t_1\}} \!  \mathrm{d}^3r~J^0({\bf r},t)\cr
~=~&\int_{\{t=t_1\}} \!  \mathrm{d}^3r~n_{\mu}J^{\mu}({\bf r},t)\cr
~=~&\int_{\{t= t_1\}} \! J~\lrcorner~ \mathrm{d}^4x~\end{align}\tag{2}$$
is a conserved Lorentz invariant.

To see that the charge (2) is a Lorentz invariant, define a charged in a primed inertial frame in a similar way
$$ Q^{\prime}(t^{\prime}_1)~:=~ \int_{\{t^{\prime}=t^{\prime}_1\}} \!  \mathrm{d}^3r^{\prime}~J^{\prime 0}({\bf r}^{\prime},t^{\prime}). \tag{3}$$

By the divergence theorem, we get

$$ Q^{\prime}(t^{\prime}_1) - Q(t_1)~=~\left(\int_{\{t^{\prime}\leq t^{\prime}_1\}}-\int_{\{t \leq t_1\}} \right)\!  \mathrm{d}^4x~\partial_{\mu}J^{\mu}(x)~=~0, \tag{4}$$
where we implicitly assume that no charge is leaking at spatial infinity.

For a related statement, see [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/671003/2451) Phys.SE post.

Comment: But OP is asking how can the charge density of a small spacetime grid have a probabilistic interpretation, despite not being invariant. The question is focused on the probabilistic interpretation